# Can't reference class library in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I do this lesson from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1010152/Learn-MVC-Project-in-Days-Day
I'am at the end lab 32. I did everything step by step but I have this error:

> The type or namespace name 'BusinessEnties' (or ViewModel) could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I add any reference to WebApplication1 I see BusinessEnties or ViewModel and I have no errors but when I build this errors back.

UPDATED

My class tree:

[image]

And dependecy map

[image]

Comment: We can't help you without seeing what you're doing.  How are you adding the reference?  Are you sure the library contains the classes you seek?

Comment: Did you add a using statement to the top of the file(s) that make use of classes in this library?

Comment: @Amy I updated question

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, but are invisible

Comment: This typically happens to me when the .Net versions don't match.  Check the type of the MVC project and Class Library.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes! My project is 4.5 and Class Library 4.5.2. I changed this and it resolved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your projects .Net versions.  If the MVC Project has a lesser version then the class Library it most likely won't work.

Comment: Found this to be the case for me. Had to upgrade the versions to match

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the classes are **Public**